# ¿Cómo cambiar el formato de Double o Float en Java?

Tags: java, float, double

no tengo muy claro como cambiar el formato de un numero tipo Double o float en Java, es decir: si tengo **63.3333333** (un numero periodico), ¿Cómo puedo conseguir que al mostrarlo en consola me muestre: **63.33**?, ¿Cómo es la sintaxis de la función que me permite conseguirlo?

Comment: esto podría ayudarte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153724/how-to-round-a-number-to-n-decimal-places-in-java

Comment: `system.out.format("%.2f", floatVarAqui);` puedes ver más ejemplos y documentación en este [enlace](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html)

Comment: Por favor Augusto, es demasiado importante agregar lo que trataste, saludos!

Comment: Pon lo que has intentado para poderte ayudar

Answer (score 0):

Puedes crear un método en una clase Util y llamar desde cualquier clase a este método. Te escribo el ejemplo.

```
public class Util{  
  public static Double formatearDecimales(Double numero, Integer cantidadDecimales) {  
    return Math.round(numero * Math.pow(10, cantidadDecimales)) / Math.pow(10, cantidadDecimales);  
  }  
}  

public class OtraClase{   
 double miNumero=63.3333333;  
 int cuantosDecimales=2;  //estos son la cantidad de decimales que quieres obtener
 double numeroConDosDecimales=Util.formatearDecimales(miNumero,cuantosDecimales);
}
```